# OS X (Unix) shell command: possible to get last opened date of file?

Tags: macos, unix, shell, automator

when you use the following command

```
find /Users/someUser/someFolder/* -type f -mtime +90
```

you'll get all the files that have a modification date that is bigger than 90 days. If you open however the file properties in the Finder on OS X for instance there is also a "Last opened" date. Is there a possibility to get all files with a last opened date bigger some treshold like the example above?? 
Sadly there's no "-otime" :)

Also on Automator you there's no filter for the last open time but just for modified time and created time...

Thanks a lot

Comment: Thanks for the information, really interesting and useful. But the atime you mentioned initially actually works perfectly for me. Thx :)

Comment: Ok! (Please consider removing the old comments below; you never know if they confuse someone in the future. Thanks!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The parameter `atime` defines the last *access* time. <strike>Seems you want that?</strike> But that is apparently not the same as the date you use in Finder.

See `ls -lu` for the date `atime` uses.

Mac OS X also uses the "HFS meta data" (or: "Finder info") to store dates. For example: Unix does not store file creation dates. The `cdate` in Unix is really the change date (including, for example, changes in access permissions, so `cdate` gets a new value in slightly different occasions than the modification date for `mdate`). Using this metadata, Mac OS X can still keep the details.

There are several options to show (some of) those dates, like:

```
stat file.txt
GetFileInfo file.txt
mdls file.txt
```

Using `mdfind` one can search for specific meta data. But it uses [the Spotlight index](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/SpotlightQuery/SpotlightQuery.html), so I guess it might not find everything.

Like to find files that are excluded from Time Machine backups:

```
sudo mdfind "com_apple_backup_excludeItem = 'com.apple.backupd'"
```

To search based on the creation date, use `kMDItemFSCreationDate`. For the last opened date: `kMDItemLastUsedDate`. But note that files which have been created through certain Terminal commands, may not have that meta data set:

```
echo "Hello world" > ~/Desktop/hello-world.txt
touch ~/Desktop/will-not-be-found.txt
mdfind -onlyin ~/Desktop 'kMDItemFSCreationDate >= $time.this_week'
```

After opening "will-not-be-found.txt" in Text Edit, you'll see the file after all.

See also the [Spotlight Query Syntax](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/SpotlightQuery/Concepts/QueryFormat.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001849-CJBEJBHH).

Comment: That's it. Sorry, should have looked up the man page before. Thx a lot anyway :)

Comment: ah ok...but it actually doesn't correspond to the "Last opened" time in finder. But could be useful though