# Setting file creation date in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, script, date, touch

I need a script to set the creation date to the modification date for a bunch of files created by my sound recorder - any way to do this? Running Mac OS X 10.4.11

Comment: Just to help you find a solution: this is stored in the "HFS meta data", in `kMDItemFSCreationDate`. (UNIX by itself has no notion of a creation date. See http://superuser.com/questions/43310/os-x-unix-shell-command-possible-to-get-last-opened-date-of-file/43319#43319 for some details, but that doesn't describe how to change it.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `SetFile` on the command line to do this however it is not included by default in Mac OS X 10.4.x (Tiger). If you have installed the Developer Tools or most of the Combo updates it is installed but in a non standard location. `SetFile` was included in `/usr/bin/` for Mac OS X 10.5 and later.

To find the command you can try using `locate` to find the location.

Assuming you have the Developer Tools installed:

```
/Developer/usr/bin/SetFile -d '12/31/2008 12:00:00 PM' nameoffile.txt
```

You can use another program called `GetFileInfo` that is installed with `SetFile` to obtain the modification date.

```
/Developer/usr/bin/GetFileInfo nameoffile.txt
```

An example script for one file:

```
#! /bin/bash
# Usage: nameOfThisScript.sh nameOfFile.txt

modifiedDate=`/usr/bin/GetFileInfo -m $1`
/usr/bin/SetFile -d "$modifiedDate" $1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Chealion! Just what I was looking for. Here's the script so far:

#!/bin/bash

for i in /Users/MacHD/Music/h2dropbox/*

do

modifiedDate=`/Developer/Tools/GetFileInfo -m $i`
/Developer/Tools/SetFile -d "$modifiedDate" $i
echo $i

done